# Regex replace character (@) but only at end of phrase

Tags: javascript, regex, sublimetext3

https://regex101.com/

want with regex detect all phrases that end with @ so in sublime text replace with empty space for example

```
DECLARE @showBrand@ VARCHAR(MAX) = '1';
DECLARE @showBrandImage@ VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @ShowBrandLink@ VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @ShowbreakLineAfterSize@ VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @showbreaklineAfterStock@ VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @showBuyBtn@ VARCHAR(MAX) = '1';
```

and get

```
DECLARE @showBrand VARCHAR(MAX) = '1';
DECLARE @showBrandImage VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @ShowBrandLink VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @ShowbreakLineAfterSize VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @showbreaklineAfterStock VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @showBuyBtn VARCHAR(MAX) = '1';
```

so as ($ - Matches the end of a string) was trying @$ or [@]$ but doesn't detect any with [@$] detects all as it would be @ only so... what is the correct way?

Comment: `/(@\w+)@/g => $1` or  `/(\w+)@/g => $1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following: **/[@][\W]/**

This regexp will check the @ character literally, and after that a single non-word character (a space for example).

Just replace what you find with a single space.

You can take a look to this regexp here : **https://regex101.com/r/eeuw30/1**

Comment: to shorten it you don't need the `[]`, `@\W` works just as well

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the space after the second @ as a boundary and write an expression, maybe similar to:

```
(.*?)(@)(\s.*)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TSGgNA/1)

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KsP9Lx/1).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Javascript implementation:

```js
const needle = `
DECLARE @showBrand@ VARCHAR(MAX) = '1';
DECLARE @showBrandImage@ VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @ShowBrandLink@ VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @ShowbreakLineAfterSize@ VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @showbreaklineAfterStock@ VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @showBuyBtn@ VARCHAR(MAX) = '1';
`;
console.log(needle.replace(/(@\w+)@/gm, '$1'));
```

I would go with `(@\w+)@` with `global` and `multiline` (`/gm`) and replace using Group 1 match.

https://regex101.com/r/Sv1zT7/1/

The result will be

```
DECLARE @showBrand VARCHAR(MAX) = '1';
DECLARE @showBrandImage VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @ShowBrandLink VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @ShowbreakLineAfterSize VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @showbreaklineAfterStock VARCHAR(MAX) = '[]';
DECLARE @showBuyBtn VARCHAR(MAX) = '1';
```